# Rails console: Does rails console maintain cache for database tables? How to disable that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, caching, rails-console

I got fk parent/child row deletion/update errors while performing deletion on parent row.So  I removed related child records from database manually. But still i am getting errors. I presume it is related to cache. One more thing i must mention here is that when i see child records, it shows me updated state of table i.e. deleted records are not visible(that may be because i fired that query first time).

Comment: Please add code examples to clarify your question. It's currently too broad and does not provide enough detail.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah whenever you make any changes to the database or for that matter even code, it wont reflect in the console, you need to do reload! e.g

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > reload!
Reloading...
 => true 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 >
```

Answer (score 4):

Add
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

in environment/*.rb

Answer (score 2):

You can run the command:

```
reload!
```

which should reload your models(along with various other things).

as seen [here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-reload-21)

Comment: As seen in the link above, it "reloads the environment". Which includes code that changes, or code that doesn't.